# Scale desktop image automatically

Tags: unity, desktop-background

I have several images I use as wallpaper that are bigger than my monitor resolution.

Is there a way to automatically scale down the images used as a background like in Windows?

Comment: What do you mean by automatic scaling? Background images are most often bigger than screen resolution and it was never a problem? What was your actual problem?

Comment: @Anwar the images that are applied on the desktop are not scaled automatically

Comment: Are you using Unity or GNOME? Give a screenshot of the problem

Comment: @Anwar I using unity

Comment: You wanted fully covered desktop wallpaper right?

Comment: When selecting a Background you have a drop-down menu "Zoom", "Scale", "Fill", etc ... Is that not enough?

Comment: @RoVo should I do it for each images?

Comment: @RoVo plus everytime that I'm back the "scale" option is not set anymore

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?